# Hide tab header on ajax:TabContainer

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Based upon my condition I only want to remove tabheader from ajax:TabContainer on button click.

My function is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function hideheadertab() {
        $('.ajax__tab_header').hide();
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

And in button click I call function like this.

```
  protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>hideheadertab();</script>", true);
  }
```

but no luck.Any trick to do this.Thanks for help.

*Note: I want to remove only tab header not whole tab.*

tab header html part.

```
<div id="ctl16_TabContainerManagePortal_header" class="ajax__tab_header">
   <span id="ctl16_TabContainerManagePortal_TabPanelPortalAddEdit_tab" class="ajax__tab_active"><span class="ajax__tab_outer"><span class="ajax__tab_inner"><span id="__tab_ctl16_TabContainerManagePortal_TabPanelPortalAddEdit" class="ajax__tab_tab">
   <span id="ctl16_TabContainerManagePortal_TabPanelPortalAddEdit_lblAEP">Some Text</span>
   </span></span></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your taheader html part..

Comment: what is it doing right now? hiding all the tab? not hiding anything?

Comment: Based upon a condition this time I have only 1 tab so in case of single tab I want to hide tab header.